# Expanding the charges response from Payment Elements in StripeJS

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using react to confirm a Stripe order using Express Elements and during that process trying to expand the charges API in the response:

```
  const {paymentIntent, error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    clientSecret,
 
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: PAGE_URL,
      expand: ['charges.data'],
    },
    redirect: "if_required",
  });
```

However if I `console.log(paymentIntent)` or even `console.log(paymentIntent.charges)` I cannot see the charges data.

I am looking at the documentation and it seems to be supported: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment#confirm_payment_intent-options-confirmParams-expand

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting anything back when you attempt to expand `charges` client-side because it's not one of the PaymentIntent attributes that's retrievable with a publishable key. If you look at the [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) you can see there are some attributes like `id` and `amount` that are explicitly marked as "retrievable with publishable key".

If you want to be able to get the list of `charges` after the Payment Intent is confirmed, your best option is to call your own server that has an endpoint that retrieves the Payment Intent with a secret key and will get the full set of attributes back from the API.